# Consulta a base de datos duplica registros al hacer JOIN en diferentes tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

tardes o noches según corresponda. Me gustaría que me pudiesen ayudar, no soy experto en bases de datos pero voy a tratar de hacerme entender.

Estoy haciendo una consulta entre 3 tablas `accidents`, `lesion`, `body`.

`accidents`: tabla en donde se encuentran los registros de accidentes de trabajo de un empleado. (Ejemplo solo hay un accidente)

`lesion`: tabla en donde se encuentran los tipos de lesiones que puede haber en un accidente. (Ejemplo hay 2 lesiones registradas para el accidente: Fractura y Herida)

`body`: tabla en donde se encuentran las partes del cuerpo que fueron afectadas. (Ejemplo hay 2 partes afectadas en el accidente: manos y cuello.

`lesion` y `body` se relacionan con `accidents` pero no entre ellas mismas

---

```sql
SELECT accidents.id, lesion.name as tipo_lesion, body.name as parte_cuerpo
FROM accidents 
INNER JOIN lesion ON lesion.accident_id = accidents.id
INNER JOIN body ON body.accident_id = accidents.id
```

---

El resultado es el siguiente:

| id | tipo_lesion | parte_cuerpo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fractura | Mano |
| 1 | Fractura | Cuello |
| 1 | Herida | Mano |
| 1 | Herida | Cuello |

Como quisiera que fuera el resultado

| id | tipo_lesion | parte_cuerpo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fractura | Mano |
| 1 | Herida | Cuello |

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Es que no lo estás haciendo mal, es el comportamiento del join de las tablas que tienes. En el ejemplo que dices que querías recibir, faltarían datos. si en un accidente hay 2 tipos de lesiones y 2 partes del cuerpo, te debería de devolver lo que te devuelve, no lo que tu dices.

Comment: Así a lo rápido pienso que está mal diseñada la base de datos. Si los "accidentes" ocurren en la tabla `accidents`, entonces no deberían existir `lesion.accident_id` ni `body.accident_id` ya que esas 2 tablas son *entidades primarias*. Debería existir es `accidents.body_id` y `accidents.lesion_id`

Answer (score 0):

Como puse en el comentario, la tabla `accidents` parece una *tabla de cruce* entre 2 tablas. En ese caso la estructura de las tablas `lesion` y `body` están incorrectas, ya que estarías añadiendo uno o más registro en cada una de esas tablas por cada accidente que ocurra.

La estructura que funciona para ese caso sería algo como:

Tabla `lesion`

```
---+-------
id | name
---+-------
1    Fractura
2    Herida
```

Tabla `body`

```
---+-----
id | name
---+-----
1    Manos
2    Cuello
```

Tabla `accidents`

```
---+-----------+---------+-----------
id | lesion_id | body_id | empleado_id
---+-----------+---------+-----------
1    1           1         1
2    1           1         2
3    2           2         2
```

Agregué la columna `empleado_id` para hacerlo más interesante, además de que esa columna posiblemente si tengas que agregarla cuando crees la(s) tabla(s) de *empleado*, también debes considerar la *fecha de accidente* (un mismo empleado puede tener varios accidentes)

Si quisieras obtener todos los daños que sufrió el empleado con `id=2` entonces:

```sql
SELECT accidents.id, lesion.name as tipo_lesion, body.name as parte_cuerpo
FROM accidents 
INNER JOIN lesion ON lesion.id=accidents.lesion_id 
INNER JOIN body ON body.id=accidents.body_id
WHERE accidents.empleado_id=2
```

Da como resultado

```
---+-------------+-------------
id | tipo_lesion | parte_cuerpo
---+-------------+-------------
2    Fractura      Manos
3    Herida        Cuello
```

Entonces, la respuesta a tu pregunta es la misma consulta, pero sin la línea del `WHERE`.